# Is it possible to share a VPN connection over WiFi Hotspot?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, vpn

I have an S8 And a Nintendo switch, The switch doesn't support VPNs. Is it possible to share the VPN Connection to my Nintendo switch over hotspot? My PC Can already do this but I want to play outside!

Answer (score 5):

Yes its possible, I have covered one method to achieve this already [on this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/170532/209414).

Alternatively, our fellow user, [Mygod](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/181631/mygod) has shared one application to achieve this called VPN Hotspot and is available both on [XDA Labs](https://labs.xda-developers.com/store/app/be.mygod.vpnhotspot) or [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/be.mygod.vpnhotspot/). As expected both these methods need **root**,  for non root solution you may have to look at something like [PDANet+](https://labs.xda-developers.com/store/app/be.mygod.vpnhotspot)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the [VPN-Client-App](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=vpn%20provider&c=apps) from any provider on your Android
2. Setup and connect the VPN (an instruction you find on the site from your vpn service)
3. Turn on the mobile Wi-Fi hotspot feature from your Android settings
   [image]
4. Then it should work!

Comment: It "should" work, except that Android deliberately prevents tethered devices from connecting to the VPN on the Android device (i.e. it won't share the VPN connection).  You need root to enable that -- or to do something else, like set up a port forward via ssh, etc.  More information at https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60819/can-i-share-my-androids-vpn-connection-over-a-hotspot

Answer (score -2):

If you run a pie rom with aosp updated kernel just enable acesses point, usb wired alternative: pdanet ... or http injector in rooted devices can run a proxy server

Comment: And the restrictions [described in this comment](/questions/194255/16575#comments-194257) no longer apply on Android 9? The second part of your post has already been covered by the answer the comment is on.